# How to clear current route when i do `history.goBack()` in react router browserHistory?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history, html5-history, history.js

My scenario is I have a form which have multiple steps before the process is completed and form is submitted and each step is represented by route.
What I want to achieve is if user clicks back button on any step, I want to clear history and want to restrict him from going forward.

For example, the form include 4 steps. If the user is on step 3 and clicks back, I want to take user back to previous route using `history.goBack()` but at the same time, I want to clear all forward history so that user cant go to step 3 using browser buttons as well, (in this case, entry for step 3 should be removed from history so that user cannot access or move forward using browser buttons).

I searched but could not find anything related to this. So posting here.